# How can I control a 4026 counter chip from my raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, electronics

I have a 4026 counter chip controlling a seven segment LED display.

The current set up is every time I press a button it advances by one digit on the display. See circuit below.

This circuit runs on 9v so I haven't been too adventurous in my testing from fear of frying the Raspberry Pi.

How can I control this with an Raspberry Pi, regarding 9v vs Raspberry Pis 3,3 volt ?

Example circuit.

[image]

Comment: Possibly but it's hard to tell from your description as the current circuit could do anything.  9V is not good for the Pi but an opto-isolator can cure that if you are concerned A basic functional overview and circuit is at https://www.petervis.com/GCSE_Design_and_Technology_Electronic_Products/4026-counter-circuits/4026-counter-circuit.html and you would replace the switch to pin 1 with an isolated signal from the Pi with a pulse twelve of a min of 100ns based on https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/CD4026%20Datasheet.pdf and 10v  Please add more details to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only output from the Raspberry Pi that should drive the 4026 7-Segment Counter there are only need for a driver circuit.

This can be done with transistors, MOSFETs or a driver IC.

A simpler way is to change the voltage for the 4026 from 9 volt to 3,3volt its within the IC's working parameter (3-15v).

And then replace the current limiting resistors to the 7-segment LED display to fit the new voltage.

And now you can interface the 4026 directly to your Raspberry Pi.

Ref.: https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/CD4026%20Datasheet.pdf

Comment: Nice idea, but it should be noted that not every 7-segment display which works with 9V will work with 3.3V.

Comment: I tried with 3 V but it isn't consistently bright, i ended up using 2N2222 transistors to interface.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Do you mean that there is 7-segment displays with built in resistors? That I have never seen.

Comment: @euan Nice, that is a appropriate solution. Did you change the current limiting resistor when you changed the voltage ?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson No, I mean displays with several LEDs in series, which need higher voltage regardless of the current-limiting resistors. Running a single led per segment display with 9V results in incredibly poor efficiency.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Do you have a part no for such display?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson For instance SC23-12EWA is a 12V part with 4 LEDs in series in each segment (except the dot).

Comment: http://descargas.cetronic.es/SC23-12EWA.pdf

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thx, now have I learned something new today also :-)