# How to generate proper pulse with python (with RPi.GPIO or pigpio) and GPIO pins to count with 4026 IC?

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio

How to generate proper pulse with python (with RPi.GPIO or pigpio) and GPIO pins to count with 4026 IC? At this question it seems it is solved, but it isn't clear how:
[How can I control a 4026 counter chip from my raspberry pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118218/how-can-i-control-a-4026-counter-chip-from-my-raspberry-pi) A 555 IC is needed for example or not?

Comment: what's a `proper pulse`?

Comment: What do you want to do?  Don't use a link to ask a question.  Ask your question in your question.

Comment: @jsotola: A proper pulse in my amateur point of view is high-low/low-high pulse which makes a 4026 counter IC work for example. I already managed to make it count with RPi.GPIO, but too fast and only after I have closed the script, or most of the time it doesn't count at all (or it is too fast and cannot be seen). With pigpio I had no success, nothing happened seemingly.

Comment: @joan: I used the link, because at first I wanted to ask at that question (and because it is related), but I wasn't able to (not enough points) and admin deleted my question as it was written there as an answer.

Comment: You have still not explained what you want to do.  You need to explain what you want to do in your question.

Comment: @solari refer to the 4026 datasheet for minimal signal timing requirements and set the RPi outputs to be within acceptable limits

Comment: @jsotola: thanks, I tried and I thought the problem is with the minimal voltage (3.3 of GPIO and tried with 5V with transistor, but no success), but finally I've found out I have connected the 4026 pins in a wrong way - facepalm emoji - so I could solve it with GPIO out directly (in the sheet 5V is only mentioned, but not needed by all means)... Thank you for your time and patience  :)